# React native get access token social networks

Tags: android, ios, react-native, social-networking, access-token

I'm working on **react-native** app project I need to use login with social networks and get access token of each others. I have problems with some packages i need the best way and cross platform (iOS, Android).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a one-for-all solution to this problem that integrates well with RN. I've been recently working with the [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk), which enables Facebook Login in your application. It's fairly easy to set up, and it might be a good starting point for you. As for other social networks, I'd suggest you go over each one and find a way that does the job. Here are some packages that might help you:

- [LinkedIn](https://js.coach/all/react-native-linkedin-login?search=linkedin)
- [Instagram]
  (https://js.coach/all/react-native-instagram-oauth?search=instagram)
- [Google](https://js.coach/all/react-native-google-signin?search=google%20login)

This also might be worth a shot: [react-native-social-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-social-auth)

Comment: Thank you @martinarroyo ! for facebook it's work to me to its pro !